# Steam train 10874 draining batteries in seconds

Tags: duplo, battery

Santa brought my son a new Steam train 10874. We assembled it and put brand new 4xAAA (1.5V) batteries. The train works for 4-5 seconds and then stops. Connected it to the app and it shows batteries are down in 5sec. On next start it is the same. Changed 2 more sets of different batteries, but it is still the same. Any suggestions?

Comment: Contact customer support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since this is entirely new set, getting in touch with [LEGO Customer Support](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service) will be your best way of addressing this issue. They will be more than happy to help you.

Comment: Yes, will try that!

Answer (score 1):

Draining batteries in five seconds should be impossible. The batteries would go up in flames.

What’s possible is that you bought fake batteries that have practically no charge. Or you picked batteries that were in a drawer for the last 20 years. Or you put in batteries the wrong way round, which should be hard with AAA batteries.

Comment: The batteries don't need to be 0% charged in order for the train motor to stop - their combined voltage just need to drop under a given value.

Comment: @zovits Motors tends to be driven by current, not voltage. Cheap batteries will have large internal resistances and can't deliver enough current...